# Using mysql in C programming

Tags: mysql, gcc, c

I installed ubuntu on a virtual machine.There,I installed mysql server(sudo apt-get install mysql-server) .This worked, because I could acces mysql-u root -p password. After that,I did : sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev.

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

  exit(0);
}
```

When I compile this with gcc version.c -o version  mysql_config --cflags --libs it works. But when I compile this one from below( gcc createdb.c -o createdb -std=c99  mysql_config --cflags --libs) I get some errors.

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
  MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

  if (con == NULL) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
      exit(1);
  }

  if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "root", "root_pswd", 
          NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
      mysql_close(con);
      exit(1);
  }  

  if (mysql_query(con, "CREATE DATABASE testdb")) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
      mysql_close(con);
      exit(1);
  }

  mysql_close(con);
  exit(0);
}
```

Errors:

```
"Usage:: No such file or directory
[OPTIONS]: No such file or directory
Options:: No such file or directory
[-I/usr/include/mysql: No such file or directory
[-L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
.
.
.
unrecognized command line option '--cflags'
unrecognized command line option '--libs'
.
.
unrecognized command line option '--socket'
unrecognized command line option '--port' "
```

Can someone explain me what I did wrong,and how to fix it?
I just want to get some data from tables in a C program.

Comment: Please do not post the same question on multiple sites. [Using mysql in c prorgramming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594507/using-mysql-in-c-programming)

Answer (score 2):

You need *command substitution* syntax around the `mysql_config` command; either with 'backticks':

```
gcc createdb.c -o createdb -std=c99 `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

or with `$(...)`

```
gcc createdb.c -o createdb -std=c99 $(mysql_config --cflags --libs)
```

Comment: This question was also posted by the same user in SO, and there are responses. [Using mysql in c programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594507/using-mysql-in-c-programming)

Comment: I had that commnad substitution syntax around the mysql_config.
Also tried $(mysql_....) ,but I get the same errors...

Comment: @untmazga I've tried with your example code and this all works. The errors suggest you're stuffing something incorrect into the shell.